# Python: Can I read a large text file from different scripts?

Tags: python

I have a large text file stored in a shared directory on a server in which different other machines have access to that. I'm running various analysis on this text file without changing or updating it. I'd like to know whether I can run different python scripts on different machines in which all of them reading that large text file? None of the scripts make any change to that file, they just need to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do multiple read access, but it might get really, really, really slow, compared to reading the same file by several scripts on the same computer (obviously, the degree will very much depend on how much reading you are doing). You may want to copy the file over before processing.